# Cant connect to a SQL database in AWS(Server was not accessible)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, firewall

I'm trying to connect to an SQL database hosted on AWS from my home but getting this error:

[image]

There is not a problem connecting to it when I'm at work but need access to it from home. The firewall on AWS has permission to let my ip through to port 1433.
Cant figure out if the problem is on my end or the server.

Anyone has a clue how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do the following:

1. Check your antivirus or firewall on your PC. You are not provided
   details. So this advice is very general.
2. Check you Wi-fi router firewall settings. It's ridiculous, but you should ensure that all correct from this side.
3. Check your DNS. `nslookup [your machine name]` 
   As far as I understand your error SQL Server Studio can't resolve hostname of your AWS machine. Try to use new DNS e.g. Google (8.8.8.8) or Cloudflire (1.1.1.1).
4. Try to check network access to AWS machine:
   `telnet [your machine name] 1433
   tracert [your machine name]`

So if you tried all of this, but nothing helps or you find that you have not network access to your machine at all (tracert and telnet will help you) I suggest you ask your Internet provider what the what is going on. You could attach telnet and tracert output to them in advance.

So that's all that I can advice you without details. Hope it somehow helps you!

Comment: Thank you so much. With your answer I could keep digging and made some changes to router configuration. Not sure if that was necessary cause I found out I also needed to specify the port in SSMS after the address. Works now!

Comment: You're welcome! Please, accept my answer if it has helped you to solve the issue.